# Concatenate URL with two variables

Tags: php, google-maps

What I am doing is getting latitude and longitude from databases and displaying it in $row['latitude'] format. Now what I want to t to do is which ever hyperlink user clicks it takes him to maps.google.com and show location against that particular latitude and longitude.

please help! Here is my PHP code.

```
    <?php

    $location=$_POST["location"]; 
    $myArray = json_decode($location,true);
    $jsonArray = $myArray[0];
    $longitude = $jsonArray['longitude']; $adress = $jsonArray['adress'];
    $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
   // Check connection if (mysqli_connect_errno())   {   echo "Failed to
   connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();   }

   $sql = "INSERT INTO chokh_db. gpslocations (     latitude,   longitude ,
   datetime     ) VALUES ( '$latitude' , '$longitude' ,  NOW() );";



 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); } $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM      _db. gpslocations where
      latitude <> 0");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {       
            $lat = $row['latitude'];    
            $long = $row['longitude']   
            echo $row['datetime'] . 
                "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" .          
                $row['latitude'] .
                "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" .
                $row['longitude'] ;      
            $url = "http://maps.google.com/?q='.$lat,$long.' "; 
            echo "<a href='$url'>View</a>";    echo "<br>";   
        }
        mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are using the $url variable that you are setting but it looks like you have a typo in setting it.

```
  ///Change this
  $url = "http://maps.google.com/?q= '.$lat,$long.' "; 

  ///To this
  $url = "http://maps.google.com/?q=".$lat . "," . $long;
```

This should produce a url of something like..

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=37.3325004578,-122.03099823
```

Comment: I am using it in echo statement below. isnt it correct?

Comment: Ahh Yes. I see it now. Looks good. Not sure how I missed it before.

Comment: any idea of how to show route of couple of latitudes and longitudes from this code? I dont know how can i manipulate this. I am getting location at certain period of time and now i want to show routes of lets day last 5 latitudes and longitudes. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write the url variable as below.

```
 $url = "http://maps.google.com/?q=$lat,$long";
```

Above string is enclosed in double quotation marks, therefore $lat and $long variables will replaced by their values. This is similar to writing it as

```
$url = "http://maps.google.com/?q=".$lat.",".$long;
```